# Can't combine <integer> and <list>

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I seem to have a simple piece of code that takes a JSON file and converts it into a nice dataframe. This JSON file is participants' data from my online study. For other datasets, this exact code works perfectly well, but on this particular dataset it gives me the following error.

`` Error: Can't combine `..1$env` <integer> and `..2$env` <list>. ``

The code itself is as follows:

`lines <- readLines(file) %>% map_dfr(fromJSON, flatten=F) -> data`

I understand that one of my variables, `env` is coming across as both an integer and a list. But why would that be. In the task, env is simply `1,2,3` and it represents different environments that the participant plays my task in.

Any leads on how to fix it? I am happy to share more details about the JSON file if needed, but put simply, it is simply a masterfile with a JSON entry for every participant on a new line.

Let me know what you all think!

Best

PS: Here is the JSON file for more info. I have deleted one line at the top because it contained some identifiable information.

```
</h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation_warning","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":13,"time_elapsed":482809,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-1.1"},{"rt":3604.9000000003725,"stimulus":"stimuli/cfd/CFD-WM-018-002-N.jpg","response":"k","faceNo":15,"test_part":"stimulus","block_no":0,"env":1,"trial_type":"image-keyboard-response","trial_index":14,"time_elapsed":486416,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-2.1","ft":0.06699166666666667},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2>+</h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"skip_fixation","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":15,"time_elapsed":487418,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-4.1-0.1"},{"trial_type":"call-function","trial_index":16,"time_elapsed":487418,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-6.1"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2>+</h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":17,"time_elapsed":488420,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-0.2"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2><mark>+</mark></h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation_warning","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":18,"time_elapsed":488922,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-1.2"},{"rt":1772.2999999998137,"stimulus":"stimuli/cfd/CFD-WM-025-002-N.jpg","response":"k","faceNo":50,"test_part":"stimulus","block_no":0,"env":1,"trial_type":"image-keyboard-response","trial_index":19,"time_elapsed":490696,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-2.2","ft":0.11793333333333333},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2>+</h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"skip_fixation","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":20,"time_elapsed":491697,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-4.2-0.2"},{"trial_type":"call-function","trial_index":21,"time_elapsed":491698,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-6.2"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2>+</h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":22,"time_elapsed":492699,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-0.3"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2><mark>+</mark></h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation_warning","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":23,"time_elapsed":493400,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-1.3"},{"rt":1173.300000000745,"stimulus":"stimuli/cfd/CFD-WF-015-006-N.jpg","response":"j","faceNo":29,"test_part":"stimulus","block_no":0,"env":1,"trial_type":"image-keyboard-response","trial_index":24,"time_elapsed":494575,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-2.3","ft":0.15525833333333333},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"stimuli/cfd/CFD-WF-015-006-N.jpg","response":null,"feedback_given":0,"test_part":"feedback","block_no":0,"trial_type":"image-keyboard-response","trial_index":25,"time_elapsed":495578,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-3.3-0.3"},{"trial_type":"call-function","trial_index":26,"time_elapsed":495578,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-6.3"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2>+</h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next
> person</mark></h4>","response":null,"test_part":"fixation","env":1,"block_no":0,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":27,"time_elapsed":496580,"internal_node_id":"0.0-6.0-1.0-0.4"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h2><mark>+</mark></h2><div
> id=\"container\"></div><h4 id = \"keys\"><mark>Press \"J\" to send
> friend request, or \"K\" to move to the next person</mark>
```

Comment: We really need to see the contents of the file to deug for you Sankalp

Comment: @AllanCameron I've added a snippet. Does that help? Something like that repeats for 12 environments for about 50 people.

Comment: The snippet is not valid json, you have way more chance to get help if you provide a working example. for sensitive data, do not change the json structure, just change the sensitive info for something else.

Comment: Hi @MerijnvanTilborg. I was trying to make a neater json to post here, but as I was doing this I realise what the problem was. I was using ```env``` to represent both the environment in a given trial, and also the environment for each trial in a block (which is a list). I changed the latter varilable name to ```trialwise_env``` and that did the trick!